# What's the best practice when it comes to aligning images horizontally in html/css?

Tags: html, css

This is how I typically do it but it usually causes issues.  Then I'll float the images but then the content below that gets screwed up because they don't float.  Suggestions?

```
 <p>This is content</p> <img src="" />
 <img src="" /> <p>This is more
 content</p>
```

Comment: I would go with display: inline. Don't know if it causes problems in your particular example, but this this the thing I always try first.

Comment: What issues? Be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Why not just don't set anything since images are by default `display:inline` anyway?

Comment: @ime Vidas `inline-block` acts differently to `inline`. But you are right, `inline` is probably appropriate for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use float, give the element "below" the floated elements the CSS `clear: both`.

Answer (score 0):

```
p { font-size:1.2em; line-height:1.5; margin-bottom:1.25em; vertical-align:middle; }
img { vertical-align:middle; margin:0 0.5em;} // margin is optional


<p>This is content <img src="/imgs/btn-notify.png" hspace="5" /> <img src="/imgs/btn-notify.png" hspace="5" /> This is more content</p>
```

**Inside** the paragraph tag is proper syntax for an inline image, and I'd recommend starting there before changing the native layout property.

Any [inline element](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html) can be used inside the `<p>` tag (take advantage).